# Disabling Android swap with ADB `swapoff`

Tags: adb, swap

I'm using non-rooted phone, how do I disable swap with ADB using `swapoff`?

It says

```
swapoff: Needs 1 argument (see "swapoff --help")
```

Here is `swapoff --help`

```
usage: swapoff swapregion

Disable swapping on a given swapregion.
```

Where to find swapregion?

Comment: `swapoff` cannot be run without root (`CAP_SYS_ADMIN` to be more precise).

Answer (score 4):

Most Android devices do not have a `swap` area like typical operating systems do. Instead, Android [manages](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-management) memory differently, using techniques such as zRAM and low-memory killers to manage memory allocation among processes

Having said that, `swap` may be created by `magisk` or related modules. To see if it's there:

```
# cat /proc/swaps
Filename            Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/block/vnswap0  partition   2097148 1472552 -1

swapoff <block device path>
swapoff /dev/block/vnswap0
```

It will most likely give you a *resource busy* error. Have to run it at boot-time.

Useful references: [Stack Overflow - Swapon failed trying to enable zram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467604/swapon-failed-trying-to-enable-zram).

Answer (score 1):

At least [since Pie](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/766b632ebc03a3965cdf5ce96563e80b94bd2f4e), it may be possible to disable swap with:

```
adb shell settings put global zram_enabled 0
```